# Laravel sending status codes with redirect

Tags: laravel, testing, status

If' in blade is a code

```
@inject('response', \Illuminate\Http\Response::class)
{{ $response->status() }} //it displays always only 200 instead of 302 or 400
<form>..login form..</form>
```

And in a controller

```
//view:
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('auth.login');
}

//submit
public function customLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return redirect()->route('index')->withSuccess('Login success');
    }
    //status code 400 not work
    return redirect(null,400)->route('login')->withDanger('Wrong password or email');
}
```

I want with redirect (not a response). I'm looking for solution that works in a browser and in test e.g C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\tests\Feature\LoginTest.php

```
public function testSuperAdmin() {
    $response = $this->post('/login', [
        'email' => 'yy@blaa.com',
        'password' => '123',
    ]);
    $response->assertStatus(400);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** You cannot do it because HTTP doesn't allow it.

---

**Long answer:** There are standards for communication on the Internet. Web servers (Nginx, LiteSpeed, Apache, etc.) and browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.) must obey these standards to work correctly. One of these standards is HTTP which was made a standard by the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF).

You can access the IETF's HTTP specification from [here](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9110.html) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20221101135444/https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9110.html)). If you look at the "10.2.2. Location" [subtitle](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9110.html#field.location) in it, you see that HTTP header-based redirection only works with 201 and 3xx status codes.

A sample code from `vendor/symfony/http-foundation/RedirectResponse.php` (which is used by Laravel):

```php
class RedirectResponse extends Response
{

    public function __construct(string $url, int $status = 302, array $headers = [])
    {

        // ...

        if (!$this->isRedirect()) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The HTTP status code is not a redirect ("%s" given).', $status));
        }

        // ...
    }

    public function isRedirect(string $location = null): bool
    {
        return \in_array($this->statusCode, [201, 301, 302, 303, 307, 308]) && (null === $location ?: $location == $this->headers->get('Location'));
    }

}
```